# The default out-of-the box template for Blazor doesn't work on mobile

Tags: blazor-server-side, .net-6.0

If I create a new Blazor application (Server-side or WASM), the default template that is provided with the Counter and Fetch Data menu items doesn't work properly on a mobile device. It run's ok on a desktop browser. Is there something setup incorrectly?

On the mobile, the menu never opens. The hamburger Menu button cannot be tapped. Apart from that, if you manage to navigate by URL to another page, the page keep loading without giving any error.

Comment: You are probably getting some errors in the browser - if you are using a chromium-based mobile browser, you can connect your mobile to your desktop and use the desktop browser to connect to the mobile browser dev tools to investigate.

Comment: Do you use chrome for that? There is a know bug for version 91 and WA.

Comment: Issue is I have only Chrome and Edge allowed for Desktops and Mobile in our enterprise

Comment: So is there any tracker or bypass here? I forgot to mention I'm on .net 6 latest preview.

Comment: @Alamakanambra I'm on server-side